# win_bison inserting _m4eof to the end of the generated parser

Tags: c++, bison

I am using bison to generate a parser, however, when compiling the parser with the MSVC, I get an error which suggests that there is an error containing too many characters at the line after the last line in my bison file.

I have written a parser for a DSL language which used bison 2.7 for windows, I recently tried to use Conan to manage my dependencies which allowed me to get a newer version of win_bison (3.3.2). I examined the generated C++ source file and I found that the end of the file contains the following snippet of code.

```cpp
#line 80 "Grammar.y" // lalr1.cc:1243

'_m4eof'
_m4eof
```

The last 2 lines prevent compilation and  generates the error messages, these lines would not appear with win_bison 2.7.

Comment: Ok. What is the question?

Comment: Why changing my version of bison has suddenly started inserting the 2 last lines which prevents me from compiling the parser source file; or how can this be circumvented.

Comment: The question without [mcve] can't be answered. Maybe missing {} on %define api.prefix parameter causes that lines to be appended.

Comment: This seems like a configuration issue, or conceivably a bug. Afaik, the only use of `_m4eof` in Bison is as the delimiter for a HereDoc used by a call to `m4_syscmd` in the `m4` scripts which dumps error and warning messages to stdout. So they shouldn't show up in the generated file, and there should be an error or warning message before the `_m4eof`. This same system was in use in v2.7, so it could be an issue with a change to your `m4` executable. Perhaps whatever shell your `m4` is using to do `syscmd` is misbehaving.

Comment: It's certainly not going to be possible to diagnose without a lot more information, including a minimal input file which reproduces the problem. (And I don't think I'll be able to help much since I don't have Windows handy. But someone might.)

Comment: Hi I'm developer of the winflexbison and I have reproduced the problem. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with M4 stuff. Could someone explain me the purpose of '_m4eof' symbol in m4_syscmd call?